# Performance issue when overusing column in flutter

Tags: performance, flutter, flutter-layout

How could I improve the performance of my app? I have to build it like on the gif, but when I have 4-500 items in the column it get's very laggy. See the delay of the hover effect at the end of the gif.

I tried to build something simmilar with Table but I couldn't create clickable rows with it, so I tried to make it using DataTable but it was worse than what you can see now in the gif.
For this I used Columns and Rows. On the long term the rows should be more complex of course which is not helping on the performance problem...

I know I should use ListView for big datasets but then it would scroll inside the card and not with the card...

How could I create something like this in a more efficient way?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried  ` addAutomaticKeepAlives: false` for `ListView`

Comment: I couldn't move the whole card when I am using ListView... With ListView I am only able to move the inside of the card which is not what I want to do.